# Xml Serialization - Render as <Data></Data>

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

I am using the XmlSerializer and have the following property in a class

```
public string Data { get; set; }
```

which I need to be output exactly like so since There's a parser at client expecting like this

```
<Data></Date>
```

When the value is null

How would I go about achieving this?
Right Now I am getting like

```
<Data/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use [XMLElementAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlelementattribute(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
[XmlElement(ElementName = "Data")]
public string Data { get; set; }
```

Comment: You can ommit the `ElemenName` within the attribute as by default the properties name itself is written.